# Sales Cloud to JDE integration - groovy - JDE actiontype not recognized

Tags: groovy, integration, jdedwards

Trying **to Create (also update) the JDE E1 addressbook, inputs are taken from OSC** , and service call is via groovy script. 
Webservice name: Customer And Contact Manager Service
Method : processCustomerAndContactV2

[Groovy script to create/update addressbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4WDz.jpg)

**response recieved:**

> Client received SOAP Fault from server : CAUSE . . . The action code
>   entered either is not one of the following codes. Valid action codes
>   are: '1' - Add; '2' - Change; '3' - Delete; RESOLUTION . . . Verify
>   that the program allows the attempted action.

I am not sure why the actiontype is not recognized.

But **I am able to create addressbook with this**
service: *RI_Address Book Manager Service*
method: addAddressBook

But unable to create/update any addressbook, who's who, phone, or email address.
Can someone let me know the correct service to be used. also the Let me know why this issue occured.